# THREAD WARNING - phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, dialog, phonegap-plugins

THREAD WARNING: ['Notification'] took '1153.449951' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
How to solve? Help me please!

Answer (score 1):

Cordova's official documentation states that:

> If your plugin requires a great deal of processing or requires a blocking call, you should use a background thread.

Use your code like this:

```
- (void)myPluginMethod:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    // Check command.arguments here.
    [self.commandDelegate runInBackground:^{
        NSString* payload = nil;
        // Some blocking logic...
        CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:payload];
        // The sendPluginResult method is thread-safe.
        [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I tried! Did not work out.